# How do I get Firefox to render space between lines correctly?

Tags: firefox, fonts, disk-usage

I am working under Ubuntu 18.04 with LXDE. The problem I am describing does not take place in Windows 10. Therefore I guess it has to do somehow with Ubuntu 18.04.
Since a few days ago Firefox does not render spaces between text lines correctly and text lines seem to be cluttered. I found this happens at least on Google Docs, Google Sheets and another website. I get a message like "Fonts cannot be loaded. Please try again later", in Google docs and Google sheets, now and then. I noticed that this problem does not happen if I use a new Firefox profile that has not ever been synchronized with my Firefox account. Nonetheless, if I use a new profile, and I try to synchronize with my Firefox account, the problem starts happening again after the synchronization has taken place.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Please find an example of [screenshot of cluttered text lines](https://photos.app.goo.gl/8JdtYdjmv1yYZAWH8)

I asked the question here also just in case this had to do with Ubuntu but I already published this question in the Firefox forum:
https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1320259

If I broke any rule posting the same question on two different forums, administrators can delete this question.

Thanks

Comment: This is certainly a CSS thing. Does the issue exist with other sites, or is it *only* Google Docs?

Comment: So far I saw it happens on Google Docs, Google Sheets and Aliexpress.com.

Comment: The problem had to do with having the zoom enabled at 170% within Firefox. Once I took the zoom back to 100%, the lines spacing got back to normal. Anyway, I tried these websites in Google Chrome afterwards and I could see Google Chrome displays line spaces correctly, even when a 300% zoom is enabled. It would be great if anyone could find any way to display spaces between lines correctly also in Firefox when zoom is enabled. For some reason Firefox in Ubuntu has problems with that.